# How to get the mouse position using three.js?

Tags: javascript, three.js

Hi I'm using IcosahedronGeometry. In that I'm adding CircleGeometry to each of its vertices. So now my requirement is when the mouse is moved towards the circle, the circle should sense the mousemove and it should move towards the mouse. So for that i have created a RingGeometry around the circle. So if the mouse move towards the ring, circle should sense the position of the mouse.

But I'm unable to get the mouse position. I'm using raycaster, is there any other alternative to find the position of the mouse?

Answer (score 8):

Raycaster is standard way for this:

```
mouse.x = ( event.clientX / window.innerWidth ) * 2 - 1;
mouse.y = - ( event.clientY / window.innerHeight ) * 2 + 1;
raycaster.setFromCamera( mouse.clone(), camera );   

var objects = raycaster.intersectObjects(scene.children);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/nhvff8ra/6/

Comment: thank you.. ur example is slightly related to my requirement... it helps me

Comment: Can you explain what's happening here? Where did the equation for mouse position arise from?

Comment: @RylanSchaeffer The equation returns a value between -1 and 1 while 0 is the center of the window.

Answer (score 2):

I did the following (some parts are omitted for brevity):

```
// Use of the Raycaster inspired by  webgl_interactive_cubes.html, in the THREE.js project examples directory
raycaster = new THREE.Raycaster();
mouse = new THREE.Vector2()
document.addEventListener('mousemove', onDocumentMouseMove, false);
window.addEventListener('resize', onWindowResize, false);
document.addEventListener('mousedown', onMouseDown, false);


function onDocumentMouseMove(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    mouse.x = (event.clientX / window.innerWidth) * 2 - 1;
    mouse.y = -(event.clientY / window.innerHeight) * 2 + 1;
}

function onWindowResize() {
    camera.aspect = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;
    camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
    renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
}

function manageRaycasterIntersections(scene, camera) {
    camera.updateMatrixWorld();
    raycaster.setFromCamera(mouse, camera);
    var intersects = raycaster.intersectObjects(scene.children);

    if (intersects.length > 0) {

    } 
    else {

    }
}

function onMouseDown(event){
   customLog("mouse position: (" + mouse.x + ", "+ mouse.y + ")");
}
```

Take a look at [this](https://github.com/Rospaccio/gravity/blob/master/WebContent/script/main3d.js) for the complete code

Comment: Hi.. thank you for ur answer.. But what about z-axis?? I want z-axis location also..

Comment: Hi. The position of the mouse is intrinsically 2-dimensional and relative to the screen. To get a 3D point based on where the mouse pointer is, you can use the raycaster and its intersectObjects function (see the manageRaycasterIntersections in my sample and take a look at the source code of [this example](http://threejs.org/examples/webgl_interactive_cubes.html) for further detail)

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking for something like this?

```
var cursorX;
var cursorY;
document.onmousemove = function(e){
    cursorX = e.pageX;
    cursorY = e.pageY;
}
setInterval("checkCursor()", 1000);
function checkCursor(){
    alert("Cursor at: " + cursorX + ", " + cursorY);
}
```

Comment: I'd suggest to read about what is three.js before posting.

Answer (score 0):

If your render is in a window or block with example absolute position the `window.innerWidth` etc. would give you wrong coordinates and attaching mouse move to entire window is just a waste of memory.

It's much better to do something like this:

```
const renderBlock = document.querySelector('#threeJSRenderWrapper');
let renderWidth = renderBlock.offsetWidth;
let renderHeight = renderBlock.offsetHeight;
const camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(60, renderWidth / renderHeight, 0.01, 100000);

// this part you can put to window resize function
camera.aspect = renderWidth / renderHeight;
camera.updateProjectionMatrix(); 
renderer.setSize( renderWidth, renderHeight );

const pointer = new THREE.Vector2();

renderBlock.addEventListener( 'pointermove', onPointerMove );

function onPointerMove( event ) {

    // calculate pointer position in normalized device coordinates
    // (-1 to +1) for both components   
    pointer.x = ( event.layerX / renderWidth ) * 2 - 1;
    pointer.y = - ( event.layerY / renderHeight) * 2 + 1;
}

// and the rest of the code for mouse intersection or wathever
```

The `event.layerX` and `event.layerY` will give you correct coordinates of the block that the `mousemove` event is attached to.