# Three JS - Convert mousemove event position to scene position

Tags: three.js

I'm a novice to ThreeJS. I'm trying to learn how, after a `mousemove` event, to convert the event's mouse pixel position to ThreeJS scene position. There are several questions asking this question on SO (e.g. [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13055214/mouse-canvas-x-y-to-three-js-world-x-y-z), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36033879/three-js-object-follows-mouse-position), [3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30860773/how-to-get-the-mouse-position-using-three-js)) and all use code like:

```
    mouse.x = (event.clientX / window.innerWidth) * 2 - 1;
    mouse.y = - (event.clientY / window.innerHeight) * 2 + 1;
```

In experimenting with this, I discovered that this produces mouse position values between 0 and 1. What I want is mouse position values in the Three JS scene. How do I convert from `[0, 1]` to scene position values?

The answers on those pages involve complicated operations with raycasting and unprojecting cameras. Can someone either provide a simpler solution, or explain why those operations are necessary?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Three JS - Rotate arrow in 3D to track mouse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70918227/three-js-rotate-arrow-in-3d-to-track-mouse)

Comment: You need to multiply the `mouse.x` and `mouse.y` normalised (i.e. 0-1) values by the size of the canvas element to get them into pixel coordinates